# Set ringtone programmatically

Tags: android, set, ringtone

I know there are several entries to this, but none of them worked for me.
I'm trying to give the user a method to select a ringtone and have it set by the application. The ringtone path needs to be stored and set later automatically (e.g. based on time of day). So I cannot simply reuse the Uri variable in memory.

So far I'm doing this via the ringtone picker:

```
Intent fileSelectionIntent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
startActivityForResult(fileSelectionIntent, 9001);
```

Anyway the onActivityResult() will get an extra that looks like this:

```
    /content:/media/internal/audio/media/55
```

And here's the function that'll actually try to set the ringtone:

```
private boolean applyRingTone(File ringtone, int ringtoneType, Context context)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringtone.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ring");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, ringtone.length());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, ringtoneType == RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, ringtoneType == RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    Uri ur = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtone.getAbsolutePath());
    context.getContentResolver().delete(ur, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + ringtone.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);   // without this uri in the next line will be null
    Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(ur, values);

    try
    {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, ringtoneType, uri);
    }
    [...]
}
```

If I ignore all the ContentValues stuff and try to use ur instead of uri I noticed in debugger its value is the same, but the filename is omitted, so just the folder.

If I go through and use uri like in the source code uri will have another number at the end, but basically looks the same as above (55). I assume that's ok since the file was removed and readded to the library. But is this really necessary anyway? Can't I just get the id in some other way?

After this function the ringtone will be set to something that appears to be out of the RingtoneManager's realm. If I go my phone's audio settings it has been set to some fallback sound that's not in the list of sounds to pick from and has nothing to do with the one I chose.

Does anybody have an idea what I can do? My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S3 (stock, no root), so it should reflect some kind of standard.